# Unexpected REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING when modifying DataWeaveResource in the Metadata API

Tags: soap-api, metadata-api, dataweave

I'm trying to create a DataWeaveResource programmatically using the metadata API. I'm able to do this just fine by deploying a metadata ZIP, but I'd like to also be able to do it with the API, so I can iterate faster.

My SOAP payload looks like this (note this was generated with Python's [zeep](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/transport.html))

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Header>
    <ns0:SessionHeader xmlns:ns0="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
      <ns0:sessionId>[REDACTED]</ns0:sessionId>
    </ns0:SessionHeader>
  </soap-env:Header>
  <soap-env:Body>
    <ns0:upsertMetadata xmlns:ns0="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
      <ns0:metadata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns0:DataWeaveResource">
        <ns0:fullName>csvSeparatorTojson</ns0:fullName>
        <ns0:content>JWR3IDIuMCANCi8vIENTViBSZWFkZXIgcHJvcGVydGllcyBodHRwczovL2RvY3MubXVsZXNvZnQuY29tL2RhdGF3ZWF2ZS8yLjIvZGF0YXdlYXZlLWZvcm1hdHMjZm9ybWF0X2Nzdg0KaW5wdXQgcmVjb3JkcyBhcHBsaWNhdGlvbi9jc3Ygc2VwYXJhdG9yPSc7Jw0Kb3V0cHV0IGFwcGxpY2F0aW9uL2pzb24gDQotLS0gDQpyZWNvcmRz</ns0:content>
        <ns0:apiVersion>58.0</ns0:apiVersion>
        <ns0:isGlobal>false</ns0:isGlobal>
        <ns0:isProtected>false</ns0:isProtected>
      </ns0:metadata>
    </ns0:upsertMetadata>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

The base64 encoded content corresponds to this dataweave script, that I took from the DataWeaveInApex example repo [here](https://github.com/developerforce/DataWeaveInApex/blob/main/force-app/main/default/dw/csvSeparatorTojson.dwl).

```
%dw 2.0 
// CSV Reader properties https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.2/dataweave-formats#format_csv
input records application/csv separator=';'
output application/json 
--- 
records
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <upsertMetadataResponse>
      <result>
        <created>false</created>
        <errors>
          <fields>ContentType</fields>
          <message>Required fields are missing: [ContentType]</message>
          <statusCode>REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING</statusCode>
        </errors>
        <fullName>csvSeparatorTojson</fullName>
        <success>false</success>
      </result>
    </upsertMetadataResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is confusing to me because there's no ContentType field documented for the [DataWeaveResource Metadata Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_dataweaveresource.htm), and it also doesn't appear in the WSDL. Also, when I ask for a description of the resource, it doesn't include a ContentType field, and it is described as apiCreatable and apiUpdatable.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <describeValueTypeResponse>
      <result>
        <apiCreatable>true</apiCreatable>
        <apiDeletable>true</apiDeletable>
        <apiReadable>true</apiReadable>
        <apiUpdatable>true</apiUpdatable>
        <valueTypeFields>
          <isForeignKey>false</isForeignKey>
          <isNameField>false</isNameField>
          <minOccurs>1</minOccurs>
          <name>apiVersion</name>
          <soapType>Double</soapType>
          <valueRequired>true</valueRequired>
        </valueTypeFields>
        ....
      </result>
    </describeValueTypeResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can anyone share some example code that creates/updates this resource?